# Simple limits question: prove sequence is null sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Use the basic null sequences to show that $\left(\dfrac{n^{10}10^n}{n!}\right)_{\large n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is
>   a null sequence.

Will someone provide a hint?

Comment: "Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given..."

Comment: @andybenji But the question indicates not to work from first principles, but instead to use basic null sequences to prove the statement.

Comment: @Ryan I think he meant it as a joke.

Comment: @Ryan Yeah, factorials are very hard to work with using the definition.  Can you think of a sequence that's greater in absolute value (after finitely many terms) than the given one but is still a null sequence?

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation

Comment: Did you try taking ratio of successive terms?

Comment: @Ryan The ratio of successive terms is $a_{n+1}/a_n= {10 ({n+1}/n)^{10} \over {n+1}}$, which tends to 0.

Comment: @Ryan Not at all. Let $a_n>0$. If $\lim a_{n+1}/a_{n}<1$ then $\lim a_n=0$. What's more, $\sum a_n$ converges.

Comment: No. Google "D'Alamberts Test" and find a proof of it.

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\lim a_n=0$, so D'Alambert serves this purpose. The proof is not that complicated. Suppose that $\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=l<1$. Choose $q$ with $l<q<1$. Then there exists an $N$ such that, whenever $n>N$ we have ${a_{n+1}}<q{a_n}$ for $n>N$. So, for $n>N$, $a_{n+1}<q^na_1$. In the first place, this means that $a_n\to0$, and in the second place, that $\sum_{n>N} a_n$ can be bounded by $a_1\sum_{n>N} q^n$ which converges. Since the $a_n$ are positive, the comparison test means  $\sum_{n>N} a_n$ converges, which means the whole sum does.

Comment: Basically, if the limit is less than $1$, the series behaves like, or better, than a geometric series with ratio $r<1$; which means that it both tends to $0$ and that it is summable.

Comment: I just provided you with a proof, and an intuitive argument. I recommend you re-read what I wrote a few times, and try understand it. For example, let $a_n=r^n$, $0<r<1$. Then clearly $\lim r^n =0$ and $\sum r^n$ converges. But $a_{n+1}/a_n=r$ for each $n$ which means that $\lim a_{n+1}/a_n =r\neq 0$.

Comment: Whatsmore, suppose that $\sum a_n$ converges. Let $s_n =\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$. Then $s_{n+1}-s_n=a_{n+1}$. But both $s_n$ and $s_{n+1}$ tend to $\sum a_n$, so that $\lim a_{n+1}=\sum a_n-\sum a_n=0$. That is, if $\sum a_n$ exists, then $a_n\to 0$. This is basic theory about series, so you can consult it in any Calculus book.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Thanks for your patience; I finally understand the proof of the claim "if the limit of the ratio of the successive terms of a positive sequence is less than 1, then the sequence is null" (and removed my stupid comments to clear up clutter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For large enough $n$, $\Bigl(\frac{n^{10}10^n}{n!}\Bigr)$ is less than $\Bigl(\frac{11^n}{n!}\Bigr)$ because $1.1^n$ is eventually larger than $n^{10}$ (to prove this take logarithms). So we only need to show that $x_n = \Bigl(\frac{11^n}{n!}\Bigr)$ is a null sequence and then an application of the Sandwich Theorem yields the result.

To this end, firstly note that $x_n$ > 0 for all n and so for n = 22 your sequence is equal to some constant greater than 0. Call this constant c.

Show that for n > 22, $\Bigl(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}\Bigr) < 1/2$ and so, roughly speaking, getting from $x_n$ to $x_{n+1}$ requires you multiplying by a number less than $1/2$.

Then write $x_n < c \Bigl(\frac{1}{2^n}\Bigr)$ for all n > 22, and as mentioned above apply the Sandwich Therorem.

Comment: Thanks Adam. The key observation is that $1.1^n$ is eventually larger than $n^{10}$. Taking logarithms, this turns out to be  clearly untrue, doesn't it?

Comment: Well let me ask you: What is log $1.1^n$ ? What is log$(n^{10})$ ?

Comment: right, and log1.1 > 0, so that (10logn)/(log1.1) > 0, and also logn is much much slower than n as n tends to infinity. Working in base 10 for example, log(1000000) = 6 < 1000000. You can formally prove that lim(log(x) / x) = 0 if you wanted to, but I assumed that this was known.

Comment: Check your original assertion "$1.1^n$ is eventually greater than $n^{10}$". This is equivalent to $\frac{log (1.1)}{10} > \frac{log(n)}n$, which is false, right?

Comment: @Ryan Not false at all. You have a (positive) constant on the left hand side, and something that tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ on the right hand side.

Comment: Oh yes, of course $1.1^n$ asymptotically dominates $n^{10}$, just as $n$ asymptotically dominates $log( n)$. I don't know what I was thinking before! Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 2):

For $n$ sufficiently large $n^{10}<10^n$. Now consider:

$$\frac{100^n}{n!}=\frac{100}{n}\cdot \frac{100}{n-1}\cdots \frac{100}{1}$$

For all $n>100:\;\;\dfrac{100}{n}\leq\dfrac{100}{101}$ so from the above: $\dfrac{100^n}{n!}\leq N\cdot\left(\dfrac{100}{101}\right)^{n-100}$ which yields

$$\dfrac{10^n n^{10}}{n!}<N\cdot\left(\dfrac{100}{101}\right)^{n-100}\;\;\text{etc.}$$

Otherwise, a nice way is to consider:

$$e^{100}=\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{100^n}{n!}$$

$\to$ series converges so the summand must be a null-sequence.